# Eliminating duplicates in a database table

Tags: sql, db2

***For those who read the original question, I am sorry it was so confusing.  I am redoing the question to make it a litte more clear (to the best of my ability)***

I have a table in DB2 that is being populated from a source database and data using conditions out of my control.  My goal is to create an expected query to make sure the data going into this target table matches what is expected.  The first 5 columns will have primary key constraints.

The source data may sometimes have duplicates in the columns that are meant to be primary keys.  So I need to let my query account for that.  Here are some examples of what the records might look like.  (Due to the privacy restrictions of the real data, I have to use generic data to illustrate)

```
Apple Banana Carrot Dog Elephant A+
Apple Banana Carrot Dog Elephant B
Apple Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant 231
Apple Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant A-
AppleJack Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant 142
AppleJack Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant 204
```

So if we consider the first 5 records as the criteria for the primary key, then we would have 3 duplicates here. The first two records would be a duplicate of each other, the next two, and the final two.  Here is the criteria I have in choosing which records to keep.

1.) If duplicates occur, eliminate records that have 6th column value = 'NR'
(There are no examples of this in my question, but it does occur in my actual data.

2.) After removing NR, if duplicates still occur, remove records where the 6th column value = numeric.  If both records are numeric, keep

3.) After checking numeric, if duplicates still occur, sort 6th column in alphabetical order and take first record.

I need my query to check these criteria while deleting at the same time.  So after my query executes, the only records that should be still there (by my understanding are as follows):

```
Apple Banana Carrot Dog Elephant A+
Apple Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant A-
AppleJack Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant 142
AppleJack Bowl Carrot Dog Elephant 204
```

I hope this is a bit more clear of what I need.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  I am forever grateful for those who have provided input!  It really does mean a lot! I'm still quite new to SQL but understand most of the basic concepts.  Thanks again for taking the time to read.

Comment: As a note:  In SQL databases "primary key" refers to a single column or group of columns that are (by definition) unique and non-NULL.  Your use of the term is incorrect.  As for helping with your question, sample SQL would help, particularly how (in your environment) you determine if a character string is numeric, partially numeric or whatever.

Comment: The delete query is feasible with the traditional method of `delete from x t1 where exists(select 1 from x t2 where t2.a = t1.a and ... );` except you'll need a rather complicated test (involving OR) in the subquery.

Comment: So sorry @GordonLinoff.  I should have clarified that a little better.  The data in this table is being populated by data from several other tables.  After all of these conditions are met, they are populated into the new table with those primary key constraints.  This query is to determine the expected results of the ETL job that is moving the data.  So, by definition, they are Primary Key columns, they just aren't primary keys in the tables in which the data is being pulled from.

Comment: The key is not to generate these "duplicates" in the first place; not removing them after the fact.

Comment: @wildplasser Thanks for your reply! I can't get too specific about details as this is privileged information.  But my thoughts were something like this.

Suppose the data is stored in a table called TABLE1.
SELECT TAB.* FROM
(SELECT A, B, C, D, E, COUNT(*) FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY A, B, C ,D, E
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) ALIAS
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 TAB ON TAB.A = ALIAS.A
AND TAB.B = ALIAS.B
AND TAB.C = ALIAS.C
AND TAB.D = ALIAS.D
AND TAB.E = ALIAS.E

I then want to be able to filter or do the counts based on this data.  The problem arises in that the 6th column isn't part of the query.

Comment: @wildplasser That is a great point.  The problem is that the records are coming from source data.  We don't have access or knowledge of how that source data is populated.  These duplicates come in our query for expected values in the target table.  So there is nothing I can do to eliminate the duplicates from the source.

Comment: RapidSQL is not a DBMS. It's a SQL client application

Comment: In DB2 you can generally do `DELETE FROM (SELECT something FROM yourtable WHERE criteria to select records that you don't want)`, so once you formulate the criteria you're done.

Comment: @mustaccio There isn't any issue with deleting the data.  The problem is arising in writing the SQL to check all the criteria before deleting.

Comment: My answer still yields the correct result, even after you changed the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially what you need is order records within groups determined by the first five columns according to your criteria: non-numeric first, then numeric, then 'NR', then order those alphabetically, and delete all except the first record in each group. So for a simplified example:

```
create table t (f1 varchar(10), f2 varchar(10), f3 varchar(10))

insert into t values ('foo', 'bar', 'A+'), ('foo', 'bar', 'B'),
                     ('jack','jill','231'), ('jack','jill','A-'), 
                     ('apple', 'banana', '142'), ('apple', 'banana', '204'),
                     ('yum','sum','NR'), ('yum','sum','42')
```

Try selecting first:

```
select * from (
  select 
  f1, f2, f3, 
  row_number() 
  over (partition by f1, f2
  order by 
    case 
        when f3 = 'NR' then 3 -- check for 'NR' first otherwise it will match the non-numeric check
        when length(trim(translate(f3,'','0123456789') )) > 0 then 1 -- non-numeric
        when length(trim(translate(f3,'','0123456789') )) = 0 then 2 -- numeric
        else 4 -- shouldn't happen anyway
    end,
    f3
    ) rn
    from t
) where rn = 1
order by f1, f2, f3
```

And delete:

```
delete from (  
  select 
  row_number() -- don't need any other columns
  over (partition by f1, f2
  order by 
    case 
        when f3 = 'NR' then 3
        when length(trim(translate(f3,'','0123456789')  )) > 0 then 1
        when length(trim(translate(f3,'','0123456789') )) = 0 then 2
        else 4
    end,
    f3
    ) rn
    from t
) where rn > 1
```

Obviously in your case you would `partition by` five columns, not two.

Answer (score 0):

Example (the filter for numeric only is rather clumsy):

```
DELETE
-- SELECT * -- for testing
FROM rubbish d
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM rubbish x
    WHERE x.a=d.a
    AND x.b=d.b
    AND x.c=d.c
    AND x.d=d.d
    AND x.e=d.e
    AND (   0=1
            -- delete NR record only if a non-NR record exists
        OR  (d.val = 'NR' AND x.val <> 'NR')
            -- d=numeric, x= non numeric
        OR  (length(translate(d.val, '0123456789' , '' )) = 0
            AND length(translate(x.val, '0123456789' , '')) > 0
            )
            -- both numeric
       --  OR  (length(translate(d.val, '0123456789' , '' )) = 0
       --     AND length(translate(x.val, '0123456789' , '' )) = 0
       --     AND d.val::integer < x.val::integer
       --     )
            -- both non-numeric
        OR  (length(translate(d.val, '0123456789' , '' )) > 0
            AND length(translate(x.val, '0123456789' , '' )) > 0
            AND d.val > x.val AND x.val <> 'NR'
            )
        )
    )
    ;
```